# Extract data from json using requests

Tags: python

how would I go about extracting data such as that below. eg extract the body style. I will be doing this for a number of entries in the api and not just one entry so I guess i will need to use some sort of loop. Thanks alot :D

```
 >>> r3 = requests.get('www.websiteexample.com/api', params=header )
 >>> print(r3)

"ListingId":4557112,"Title":"Audi A4 Luxary Ship for Sale 2005","Category":"0001-0268-0271-","StartPrice":17985.0000,"StartDate":"\\/Date(1457637570103)\\/","EndDate":"\\/Date(1458242370103)\\/","ListingLength":null,"IsBold":true,"AsAt":"\\/Date(1457680107428)\\/","CategoryPath":"\\/Trade-Me-Motors\\/Cars\\/Audi","Region":"Northland","Suburb":"Whangarei","NoteDate":"\\/Date(0)\\/","PriceDisplay":"$17,985","HasFreeShipping":true,"BodyStyle":"Sedan","Doors":0,"EngineSize":2000,"Make":"Audi","Model":"A4","Odometer":61988,"Year":2005,"Transmission":"Automatic","Fuel":"Petrol","NumberPlate":"ABC123","BestContactTime":"Evening","Cylinders":0,"Owners":0,"Vin":"WAUZZZ8EX5A457186","WofExpires":"\\/Date(0)\\/","RegistrationExpires":"\\/Date(0)\\/","StereoDescription":null,"ExteriorColour":"Dark Blue","ImportHistory":null,"IsDealer":false}],"FoundCategories":[]}'
```

The output above is just a small extract (too long otherwise)

Comment: Use the python `json` [library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

Answer (score 1):

[Reading the documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/), surprisingly the *first* example from the first google match for `requests` on the first screen tells how to get the json body:

```
>>> r3 = requests.get('www.websiteexample.com/api', params=header )
>>> struct = r3.json()
```

Then you could for example print all top-level objects like this

```
>>> for k, v in struct.items():
...     print(k, v)
```

Or `FoundCategories`:

```
>>> struct['FoundCategories']
[]
```

Comment: when i do that and add + "AAAA" , it prints out all the terms in one dictionary (which is indicated as there is only one AAA at the end). I am trying to get the items out individually

Comment: @musss I wouldn't know, you **didn't** post the full contents, or the proper response, thus I cannot answer the exact question.

Answer (score 0):

Not very well structured question but you could use the json_normalize from pandas `from pandas.io.json import json_normalize` to extract data from json. This is not from requests though.

```
import urllib, json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

url = "www.websiteexample.com/api"
response = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(response.read())
data2 = json_normalize(data)
```